# Why measure not work: restart counting when the policy no is changed in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm calculating measure to find a credit value for the policyholder in the following way

**My table is**

[image]

The output I need is Total SA

[image]

My code is

```
Total_SA =
VAR initial_amount = 500
VAR current_index =
    MIN ( 'Table'[Index] )
VAR previous_policy =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( 'Table'[Pol No.], 'Table'[Index], current_index - 1 )
VAR cumulative_inc_sa =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Incremental SA] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Index] <= current_index )
    ) + 0
VAR cumulative_ref_sa =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Referral SA] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Index] <= current_index )
    ) + 0
RETURN
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Pol No.] ) == previous_policy,
        initial_amount + cumulative_inc_sa + cumulative_ref_sa,
        IF ( initial_amount <= 500, initial_amount, initial_amount = 500 )
            + IF ( cumulative_inc_sa < 200, cumulative_inc_sa, cumulative_inc_sa = 100 )
            + IF ( cumulative_ref_sa < 300, cumulative_ref_sa, cumulative_ref_sa = 0 )
    )
```

**output:** getting the wrong result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this below measure-

```
total_sa = 

var initial_amount = 500
var current_index = MIN('Table'[Index])
var current_policy_no = MIN('Table'[Pol No.])

var cumulative_inc_sa = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Incremental SA]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Index] <= current_index
        && 'Table'[Pol No.] = current_policy_no
    )
) + 0

var cumulative_ref_sa = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Referral SA]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Index] <= current_index
        && 'Table'[Pol No.] = current_policy_no
    )
) + 0



RETURN initial_amount + cumulative_inc_sa + cumulative_ref_sa
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `ALL ( 'Table' )`, you are removing the `Pol No.` filter context. To keep that, use this instead:

```
ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Pol No.] )
```

so that your measure is

```
Total_SA =
VAR initial_amount = 500
VAR current_index =
    MIN ( 'Table'[Index] )
VAR cumulative_inc_sa =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Incremental SA] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Pol No.] ),
            'Table'[Index] <= current_index
        )
    ) + 0
VAR cumulative_ref_sa =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Referral SA] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Pol No.] ),
            'Table'[Index] <= current_index
        )
    ) + 0
RETURN
    initial_amount + cumulative_inc_sa + cumulative_ref_sa
```